# RSpec and Cucumber with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

After running command "ruby script/cucumber" it produces the error as

```
Using the default profile...
e:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement
e:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:440:in `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Cucumber::CODEPAGE
(NameError)
    from e:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
    from e:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.3/bin/../lib/cucumber/formatter/unicode.rb:30:in `puts'
    from e:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.3/bin/cucumber:13
    from script/cucumber:9:in `load'
    from script/cucumber:9
```

Answer (score 1):

I have reopened a previous ticket for this: https://rspec.lighthouseapp.com/projects/16211-cucumber/tickets/561-uninitialized-constant-cucumbercodepage-nameerror#ticket-561-6 (Apparently I haven't resolved it).

It's a little hard for me to reproduce since this only seems to happen on Windows 7 (which I don't have).

Answer (score 0):

Folks, can you see if my latest fix fixes this problem? Look towards the bottom of the Lighthouse ticket.